# Firefox automation not working (using Selenium in Eclipse)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I m pretty new to both Java and Selenium, and i was trying a program to get Firefox up and running using a Webdriver. Here's the code i used

```
    package testPackage1;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

    public class FirefoxAutomationTest {

      public static void main(String[] args){

          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");

          }
     }
```

All this does is open and close the firefox window, it does not load google, and it throws a `UnreachableBrowserException`. However when i used `HtmlUnitDriver` instead of `FirefoxDriver`, everything seems to be working fine. Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a common issue with Selenium? How do i fix this?

EDIT: List of dependencies i have added:

- selenium-api-2.35.0.jar
- selenium-java-2.35.0.jar
- selenium-server-2.35.0.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
- selenium-firefox-driver-2.35.0.jar

UPDATE: Been trying a lot of things to get this working, and it seems i can open html pages which are saved on my hard disk, but the browser quits itself even if i m not explicitly specifying `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()`. Nothing is shown on the console, so i guess i am safe to assume that it doesn't throw any error. Also, I guess the `webDriver` produces a webpage with the following info before quitting:

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line Number 36, Column 1:<window id="main-window"
^
```

Now i tried the url shown on the above, and it leads to some part of the firefox interface. What's going on?

Comment: more information https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841

Comment: But I'm currently running Firefox 17.0.9, I guess that issue is caused only due to Firefox 22. am i right?

Comment: How do i check the Webdriver version? I am currently using selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0, if that is of any help

Comment: Ok. That's correct. Also, are you using the following jar file ? selenium-java-2.35.0.jar

Comment: Yes, i m using the mentioned file too.

Comment: Are these all the JAR files we need? Do i need to add anything more to the build path to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm flabbergasted why this wouldn't be working. The `FirefoxDriver` is actually bundled with the Selenium API by default, so if you are including `selenium-java-2.35.0.jar` and `selenium-api-2.35.0.jar` I'm not entirely sure what's happening.

Once more, make sure you have..

- selenium-java-2.35.0.jar
- selenium-api-2.35.0.jar

And if including these don't work, then include the firefox driver manually.

- selenium-firefox-driver-2.35.0.jar

Mind you that all of these libraries need to be included in your build path somehow.  As external jar dependencies, or maven dependencies, whichever you are working with.

Comment: Yes, i had missed out on adding selenium-api-2.35.0.jar. Now the UnreachableBrowserException is not thrown, instead i get this:  "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not found: 39d02ee6-69c1-4cec-bcfb-8071dc2f9730
Command duration or timeout: 20.58 seconds"  Any fix?

Comment: I am currently running firefox 17.0.9 ESR on my system, if that's of any help

Comment: EDIT: That was a freak one time only event i guess, back to getting UnreachableBrowserExceptions now. What's going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Any specific requirement to use `HtmlUnitDriver`?

**Solution :**

- Add all *.jar* which are included in dependancies
- Check their paths are valid and correct in *build_path*
- Verify firefox *compatibility* with your selenium version [Might needs to upgrade or degrade any of the component]
- Make sure you have *latest java* version installed and currently pointed correctly
- Remove *proxies* from your machine
- Connect to *open network* for using internet
- Add implicit wait to wait till *page get loaded* completely

It should solve your issue, Give a try!